# Why would an iPad change its name?

Tags: ipad, ios

Around six months ago, I bought an iPad Pro to replace a stolen iPad 2.

I set it up (if memory serves) from the backups of the stolen one and expected it to also inherit the name (since several times when I've obtained a new device, I've had difficulty deactivating the old one due to identical names.  But after a while, when importing photos, I noticed Photos.app labeling it "iPad (4)"  I wondered about the (4) but thought maybe it means this is the fourth iPad I've owned.

Until one day, Photos started saying "iPad (7)" and then a few days after that, I noticed Safari was offering me pages I had viewed on "iPad (7)"

So, I picked up the iPad, went to Settings → About, and sure enough, the iPad's name is "iPad (7)"

When I have assigned a name to a device, it has always been descriptive of the model.  When I didn't, Apple has in the past always used my name, apostrophe-S, and the model.

**What do the (4) and (7) mean, and why did they change?**

Comment: This is from DHCP.  How many other people have iPads in your house? If you have multiple iPads with the same name (i.e. "iPad") it will append a "(X)" to create a different name so it has a different name on the network.

Comment: I don't have a house, and the place where I am renting a room has two other people.  One I know doesn't have an iPad, and the other, I am not sure.  One girl went home to Poland, and this guy showed up shortly after.  That might have been when it changed; not certain.  But if that's it, why would it jump from four to seven?  And where I was before here, there was one other person.  Before that, two, but no iPads.  Not sure how long ago I noticed the (4).

Comment: So if I change it myself to something unlikely for anyone else to have, it will stay?

Comment: It should.  Change it as you suggest.

Comment: Actually if you reset network settings the phone will rename itself to "iPhone" Some people find success by manually renaming the phone. It seems to be a common issue on Macs too.

Comment: It's not a phone, and telling someone to reset network settings without warning them what they will lose if they do it is rather mean.

Comment: Well, the iPad settings now shows the name as 伟思礼 but it is still iPad (7) in Photos, iTunes, and Safari.  It is on the same WiFi SSID as the MBP, and its sync cable is also plugged in to the MBP.

Comment: I just remembered I have a network admin app, so I looked.  It shows my MBP, my iPad, the router and three "generic" devices.  one should be my android phone, and one the neighbor's Windows 10 laptop.  third, who knows.  In IOS 11, Apple took away the ability for an app to get the MAC address of another device, which makes things a little harder for for network maintenance while doing NOTHING for privacy (because there are still other less convenient ways to get them.

Comment: Interesting that Fing shows the name as "weisili"—they converted my Chinese name to pinyin minus the tone marks.

Comment: After I rebooted the iPad, it passed its new name on to the MBP.  So, Allan, you answered the question in a comment.  Perhaps you'd like to file a proper answer and add some of the details we discussed?